# Impure Korban and ketoires that started to burn become completely pure

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, words, korban, fire-burning

I was just in a shiur where they said that a korbon and kitoires which where tomai become tohor after part of them starts burning

Where can I find this(in the gemoro and the rambam)?
What is this idea called so that I can search for it?
Thank you

Comment: What i found now zevachim 43b

Comment: Rambam psulai hamikudashim 3.9-10 and 18.21

Comment: So Rambam said פקע איסור מהם but the uncleanness,  are you sure that she is also canceled?

Comment: @kouty yes see Rashi on the gemoro, and the comtentery on the rambam, http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=103612&rid=8759 search for the word טמא, rambam there 18.21 says clearly tuma ופגול או נותר או **טמא** שהעלן לראש המזבח משמשלה האור ברובן פקע איסורן מהן